# excel - how to copy all sheets from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

i have a workbook called "test". I want to copy all of the sheets in a workbook called "estimate" to test. i dont know how to create the list of sheets on "estimate" that can be copied to "test". Is there a way to do that in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim b1 As Workbook, b2 As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet

   Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\test.xls"
   Set b1 = ActiveWorkbook
   Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\estimate.xls"
   Set b2 = ActiveWorkbook

   For Each sh In b2.Sheets
      sh.Copy after:=b1.Sheets(b1.Sheets.Count)
   Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list them

```
Sub list()
Dim wbEstimate As Workbook
Set wbEstimate = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsList As Worksheet
Dim numSheets As Integer
numSheets = wbEstimate.Sheets.Count
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(numSheets)).Name = "list"
Set wsList = Worksheets("list")
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each Sheet In wbEstimate.Worksheets
    wsList.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet.Name
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

And this should copy them ***if they are both open***

```
Sub list()
Dim wbEstimate As Workbook
Set wbEstimate = ThisWorkbook
Dim wbTest As Workbook
Set wbTest = Workbooks("test.xlsx")

For Each Sheet In wbEstimate.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy after:=wbTest.Sheets(wbTest.Sheets.Count)
Next
End Sub
```

And if you need to open the test one before you copy sheets, do it like this -

```
Sub list()
Dim wbEstimate As Workbook
Set wbEstimate = ThisWorkbook
Dim wbTest As Workbook
Set wbTest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\path\to\test.xlsx")

For Each Sheet In wbEstimate.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy after:=wbTest.Sheets(wbTest.Sheets.Count)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i will test out your code in a few minutes. you certainly put some effort into this. like that you split this up in three different code boxes. i can work with that.